# How to pass down option -f SomeMakefile to a sub-make? [here with GNUMake]

Tags: makefile

When invoking itself recursively via some `$(MAKE) foo` in recipes, `GNUMake` passes down some of the options it was called with, but not all of them. In particular it does not pass down a `-f SomeMakefile` option. See [section 5.7.3 of manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion).

How can I find whether `make` was invoked with some `-f` option and how can I pass it down to a sub-make ?

To make the question concrete, here is what my `SomeMakefile` contains:

```
%.pdf : %.tex
    pdflatex $(PDFLATEXFLAGS) $*
    @if [ -f $*.log ] ; then $(MAKE) --silent $*.slw; fi
```

The problem is that how to make `foo.slw` is defined in `SomeMakefile` and the recursive `make` won't use it.

Comment: can you put the sections of the Makefiles here and how you called the command make?

Comment: I cannot put sections of the Makefiles in this comment because newline ends the comment !!! Will do it in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the name of the makefile from [`MAKEFILE_LIST`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029) variable. E.g.:

```
${MAKE} -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

If your makefile includes other makefiles you may like to store the name of the makefile early into an immediately assigned variable, e.g.:

```
# Somewhere at the top of your makefile, before any includes
this_makefile := $(lastword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

# and use it later
some_rule :
    ${MAKE} -f ${this_makefile}
```

Alternatively, if you know that your makefile is always the first one read by make, then it is going to be in the front of `MAKEFILE_LIST`, e.g. `$(firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this variable. Using it will probably require some tweaks since my `SomeMakefile` has `include`s :-(

Comment: @phs added more details for your case with multiple includes.

Comment: @M.E.: This works great and solves my problem. (But I'm still curious about recognizing `-f` options and testing them).